# What to do with unanswered old questions?

Tags: support

If there is an unanswered old question, how I can make it reviewing by people? My reputation is low, so I can't put bounty on it!  Can I ask it again?

Comment: You can drop by chat and ask people to take a look

Comment: You can earn rep and then put a bounty on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, your options are:

- earning reputation by helping others and then invest that reputation into bounties on the questions you care about.
- discuss the question with others in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) or share the question with people you know on other platforms.
- edit the question to improve it. When a question is edited, it will be bumped to the front page again. An improved question can attract new answers from people who couldn't previously help.